# Graphx Scala Vertices alwayses return me 0

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-graphx

I'm tring to implement this Graphx example:

```
import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.spark.graphx._

val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("GraphX Example")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

// Create an RDD of vertices
val verticesRDD = sc.parallelize(Seq((-1L, "nowhere"), (1L, "yahou"), (2L, "sanae"), (3L, "hanane"), (4L, "said"), (5L, "halima")))

// Create an RDD of edges
val edgesRDD = sc.parallelize(Seq(Edge(1L, 3L, "commenter"), Edge(1L, 3L, "suivre"), Edge(2L, 3L, "commenter"), Edge(2L, 5L, "connecter"), Edge(4L, 2L, "connecter")))

// Create the graph with the default vertex
val graph = Graph(verticesRDD, edgesRDD, "nowhere")

graph.vertices.collect.foreach(println)
graph.edges.collect.foreach(println)

val numVertices = graph.numVertices
val numEdges = graph.numEdges

println(s"Number of vertices: $numVertices")
println(s"Number of edges: $numEdges")
```

and it returns me always 0 on `$numVertices`

it doesn't seem that something is wrong

PS: In my example i expect the result to be 6

Comment: I could not reproduce your problem. What version of spark are you using?

Comment: works fine as-is in spark 2.3.1.

Comment: i use spark 1.6.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue finally was with:

`val conf = new SparkConf(). setAppName("GraphX Example") val sc = new SparkContext(conf)`

so when i use it two times in a spark-shell it shutdowns automaticlly

the solution is that i restart my machine and rexecute the script without these two lines and it worked, thank you all